# Cross domain JSONP post gives console error

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I want to do a cross domain post, and it seems I have to use JSONP. My post actually works, but the Firefox console gives an error. Why does the script say it 'fails' while my PHP recieved the data correctly?

```
function post_data(data1, data2, data3) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        data: "data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2 + "&data3=" + data3, 
        url: 'http://www.thedomainname.com/recievedata.php',
        success: function(data){
            alert('succes!!');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('fail!');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

it fires the error function; in this case, it alerts 'fail!'

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: it fires the error function; in this case, it alerts 'fail!'

Comment: I dont really know exactly why, but if you do a trace, you'll see that the request changes it's type from POST to GET using "jsonp", so, if the server does'nt expect that request, you'll get the 404 error response and that will launch the "error" event.  what I've done is to change it to "text" and on the success function, aply an eval over the retrieved data... I hope this helps to you... I almost forgot: This "solution" doesn't work on IExplorer

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify the following parameters (`jsonp`, `jsonpcallback`) in order to set a custom function in case of jsonp request success:

```
function jsonpCallback(response){
    console.log(response);
}

function post_data(data1, data2, data3) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp', 
        data: "data1=" + data1 + "&data2=" + data2 + "&data3=" + data3, 
        url: 'http://www.thedomainname.com/recievedata.php',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        error: function(){
            alert('fail!');
        }
    });
    return false;
};
```

Take a look here and search by `jsonp`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/